# Recommended books for Spin Geometry

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I would like you to tell me about the best introduction book for spin geometry, in particular, the following topics:

1. Clifford Algebras from the foundation to the classification and their representations.
2. Dirac operator and spinor.
3. Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem, heat kernel and its application to topology and physics.

Once, I consider about "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelsohn, but my knowledge is

1. Geometric topology(homotopy group, (co)homology and K-theory).
2. Differential geometry(Riemannian geometry, de-Rham theory and Hodge theory).
3. Representations for Lie algebras and Lie groups.
4. Functional analysis.

However I have not learned characteristic classes. To read the book of Lawson, is it poor? Should I learn about characteristic classes before index theorem? Or, please tell me another good book. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this online book : https://hal.science/hal-03015551/document ?

Comment: "I would like to tell me about the best...."  Have you told yourself the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm far from an expert on these things, but I think that you might find Andreas Rosén's [Geometric Multivector Analysis: From Grassmann to Dirac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0818K2G7L) useful. It starts out with exterior and Clifford algebras, and ends with Atiyah–Singer. At least the parts that I have read so far are very nicely written.